# How to draw an impedance in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice

I can draw a resistance or conductance in LTSpice, but how can I draw an impedance component? I've seen them drawn as unfilled rectangles before. I've tried searching the component list for "impedance", but nothing relevant shows up.

Do I have to split it into reactance and resistance?

[image]

Comment: look for inductor or capacitor = these are regular called non-resistive impedances.

Comment: I want a single component with "full" impedance, i.e. an element that is both resistive and reactive.

Comment: Why not draw it as R in series or parallel with X. I'm know you've said this but it seems so trivial and maybe you have a better reason?

Comment: I'm doing homework simplifying a circuit diagram using a method where I rewrite all resistors, caps and inductors as complex impedances and then simplify. Being able to use images from LTSpice would be useful. But in any case, having a single component would look neater according to me. I'm wondering if it is possible.

Comment: @Andyaka This is what I'm looking for: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Impedances_in_parallel.svg/301px-Impedances_in_parallel.svg.png

Comment: You can actually pretty much easily create your own device assembling all the components LTSpice proposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for in are called devices, and you combine devices (some non-linear, some linear) to get the result you need:

```
B = GaAsFet
C = Capacitor
D = Diode
E = Voltage Controlled Voltage source
F = Current controlled Current source
G = Voltage Controlled Current Source
H = Current controlled Voltage Source
I = Indépendant Current source
J = JFET
K = Mutual coupling
L = Inductor
M = Mosfet
N = Digital Input
O = Digital Output
Q = Bipolar Transistor
R = Resistor
S = Voltage controlled switch
T = Transmission Line
U = Digital device
V = Indépendant Voltage Source
W = Current controlled Switch
X = subcircuit call
```

alternatively you can use the .MODEL statement and AKO reference (AKO = A Kind Of syntax)